# How to fix [ShareSheet] cancelled request - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument

Tags: swift, swiftui, files-app

Can't save file from SwiftUI app.
Xcode says

```
[NSExtension] Extension request contains input items but the extension point does not specify a set of allowed payload classes. The extension point's NSExtensionContext subclass must implement `+_allowedItemPayloadClasses`. This must return the set of allowed NSExtensionItem payload classes. In future, this request will fail with an error.
```

```
[ShareSheet] cancelled request - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument
```

Code which I was trying

```
let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Your file is in your sandbox. Other processes don't have access to it.